# How do you convert an SSH private key to a .ppk on the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, putty, cmd.exe, openssh

I have generated a key pair with `ssh-keygen`. I now want to use the same key pair with PuTTY-based applications.

Because I'm working in a CLI environment, I want to convert the key to the `.ppk` format from within this environment.

Apparently, you can use `puttygen openssh_private_key -o output_filename.ppk` on UNIX-like environments. But the Windows version of `puttygen` will just load the key and prompt you to use the GUI to export the key.

[Batch mode for Windows PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/puttygen-batch.html) suggests that this simply is not currently possible, at least with `puttygen`. I'd gladly accept and option that uses other means though.

How can I convert the key from the command line?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) supports [command-line conversion of private keys from the OpenSSH (or ssh.com) format to the PuTTY `.ppk` format](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#keygen).

Use the `/keygen` switch:

```
winscp.com /keygen mykey.pem /output=mykey.ppk
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

Or, you can compile/run the [Unix command-line `puttygen`](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/putty-tools/puttygen.1.en.html) using Cygwin.

Or install them using WSL:

```sh
sudo apt install putty-tools # for ubuntu
```

Then, in both cases:

```sh
puttygen mykey.pem -O private -o mykey.ppk
```

---

Or build your own tool from PuTTY code. It's open-source. It is rather easy (that's basically what WinSCP does).

Use the `import_ssh2` to load the `.pem`:

```c
ssh2_userkey *import_ssh2(const Filename *filename, int type,
                          char *passphrase, const char **errmsg_p);
```

Use the `ppk_save_f` to save it as the `.ppk`:

```c
bool ppk_save_f(const Filename *filename, ssh2_userkey *key,
                const char *passphrase, const ppk_save_parameters *params)
```

Comment: Thank you! That actually works betty than using `puttygen` from the command-line because in Windows, `puttygen.exe` does not support all of the same commands that it does in Linux, so you end up with [this error](https://superuser.com/questions/1809200/unrecognised-option-while-using-puttygen-in-windows-cmd) without using WinSCP to do it.

Answer (score 27):

**NOTE: The OP requires Command line. This answer uses a graphical application... Will leave the answer here just in case it is useful.**

There is a possibly simpler solution.

1) Download (if you do not already have it) the PuTTY Key Generator (PuTTYgen) application by going [here](https://www.putty.org/) or [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

2) Open PuTTYgen

3) Click Conversions, then click import key

4) Locate your key file, then click open.

You can now save your key as a PPK file by clicking the Save private key button

You can also save a public version of your key by clicking the Save public key button

https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-windows/

https://kb.site5.com/shell-access-ssh/how-to-convert-ssh-keys-to-ppk-format/

Comment: The question is about *"Windows command line"*.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - You are correct, I will make a note on it. I could as well remove it, but I have seen very often similar cases where readers judged answers useful anyway. And this is the main goal of SO.

Comment: This anwer may not be as useful as just referring to the official documentation for this program at https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-puttygen although admittedly this answer is shorter.  But at the time of this writing the first link is to https://www.putty.org which is not positively referred to by  https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/AppendixA.html#faq-putty-org so I feel I should downvote this as more likely to cause more harm than help (unless I later notice this answer is fixed in a change newer than 2022-July-10 about 7:45am PST)

Answer (score 12):

If you're running on linux or generating your key there (or maybe you can?) then you can use

`puttygen -t rsa -C "my home key" -o mykey.ppk`

If you don't have puttygen already, then `sudo apt install putty-tools` or the appropriate command on your system to install it.

Otherwise if you're on windows I can't see how you can actually do it, other than generating the key on another machine.

Comment: This is what I use so far but one annoyance is that in Windows at least, it leaves the puttygen window open, havent found a way to automatically close it

Comment: Best answer. No manual downloads, just `sudo apt install putty-tools` and then the above `puttygen` command, and you're done. You can put the path to the original key instead of `"my home key"`.

Comment: The best answer? OP is asking for conversion not creating an rsa key in ppk format. Most people upvoting because they found this helpful to them in another case but clearly this answer did not follow OP request.

Comment: @KalibZen The author only states that he is working in a client environment on windows. The WSL2 can do the job with this answer.