# How to convert an existing private key into ppk format using ssh-keygen?

Tags: linux, putty, ssh-keys, rsa, private-key

I have a private key `private.key)` in format `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----IEpAIBAAKCAQEAvKwuhMiQR/THmjK.....-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, and I am trying to convert it in the format that putty (.ppk) understands using ssh-keygen command through cygwin, but i am getting a public key instead. Do I need to save the original file (private.key) in any specific format?

I tried saving the (private.key) in .pem format and no extension.
Tried `ssh-keygen -t rsa -e -f private.key > privatekey2.ppk`
Tried `ssh-keygen -t rsa -i -f privatekey2.key`
Tried `ssh-keygen -p`
Expecting the key in below format:

````
Comment: imported-openssh-key
Public-Lines: 6
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCiud9bCgiaSX7ck2Y1orbH3U5+4lsOmAbT
Az361YM3XwX6nLNyPycFkTdYfX75IhUPCT9ywPm4WvEy9B78qL6EoKZctAM/DUZA
7DDJeeK4NWsulN4qDUyWoR50wVJCswgwMLCZPwcXeyed8WpUi2qbi8Di4KJphdtV
HIAeq2pDYaj1HMBtxI2Lrd5DPSt7u28v/twrOksDpSA7DXzRu7AsIKvO/dF9/PR4
WB/cqctC9RPvDK1VWNj+xPFGZ2ylBr0aC3TilbKaou/8S2AmJyp5FOGUEBCUMGWs
P/fQbN0XQX6dQuvfTtYUBf4ZuJKxhPDBKiacUg5YufXdNR3I/JIx
Private-Lines: 14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Private-MAC: 22f55dc7c54402157df04950dsf67d8473bb5476f```
````

Comment: Dupe https://superuser.com/questions/912304/how-do-you-convert-an-ssh-private-key-to-a-ppk-on-the-windows-command-line

Comment: It has good answers for Windows, but OP apparently wants a Linux/Cygwin shellscript.

Answer (score 9):

You **cannot** do this with OpenSSH's ssh-keygen; it can neither import nor export PuTTY's key format.

(Your `-e` and `-i` options don't work because they have absolutely nothing to do with PPK. The manual page actually says it'll output RFC4716 format keys, which is a *very different thing.*)

To make a PuTTY PPK file, you need `puttygen`:

```
$ puttygen private_key.key -O private -o private_key.ppk
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Grawity, no the manual, just says RFC4716 key format for private key. Can we use puttygen on cygwin?

Comment: Yes, PuTTY and its tools are available for all Linux/Unix systems, so they should work on Cygwin as well. (I don't know if there's a package or if you need to compile manually.)

Comment: Of course, if you only want a one-time conversion (instead of an automated method), you could just use the Windows version (puttygen.exe) – it can import OpenSSH private keys through the menu.

Comment: No, cygwin doesnt have package for puttygen. No, want to do it through command line in shell script, so can't use windows version.

Comment: The package is probably named `putty` or `putty-tools`, that's what other distros call it. (If that is not available either, then you will have to compile the PuTTY source code yourself. Disable GTK support, disable docs, and it should be quick.)

Comment: @pratiksharma+ the ssh-keygen man page is no longer as clear as ut used to be but [RFC4716](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4716) is a file format for public key only, not private.

Comment: @Grawity, you mean, custom code to convert the key to .ppk format? Putty's code is available in 'C', and i am using shell for my operations.

Comment: I have rhel7 server, cant download the puttygen package or it is not available. What is the other way?

Comment: So rhel7 or cygwin?

Comment: For RHEL, the `putty` package is available from EPEL, see e.g. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-putty-in-redhat-linux-8 or https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=putty. For Cygwin, as I mentioned, compile it from source.

Comment: Trying both, for testing purpose using cygwin, but the shell script would actually run from rhel7.