# Unrecognised option while using puttygen in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, rsa, putty

I installed PuTTYgen on Windows using: putty-64bit-0.79-installer.msi (which I downloaded from the official PuTTYgen website).

Except that when I go to Windows cmd and run `puttygen -V`, I get the error *"Unrecognised option -V"*. What's worse is that this message is displayed regardless of the option entered.

I have to use PuTTYgen as a batch script without going through the interface to transform an `id_rsa` file into `id_rsa.ppk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows PuTTYgen is mostly GUI only. It seems that you expect it to support the command-line options that Linux console `puttygen` does. It does not.

Instead, you can use WinSCP console, which [supports some console `puttygen` functionality](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#keygen):

```
winscp.com /keygen id_rsa -o id_rsa.ppk
```

WinSCP does not support the `-O` switch, but the `-O private` is the default (and the only) conversion it supports.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

For other options, see:
[How do you convert an SSH private key to a .ppk on the Windows command line?](https://superuser.com/q/912304/213663)